# How to generate MySQL Workbench Detailed Model Report?

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

I am using the 5.2.15 OSS Beta version of MySQL Workbench. I have seen somewhere MySQL Workbench Detailed Model Reports (nice HTML version of the entire Model, gives details of the schema). I don't however see any link in the workbench that can generate such a report. Is there a plugin for this or is this feature no more available now?

Also, is there any way to generate the Inserts (that we see on the Inserts tab on the table details for our model) to be generated from a script file. It would be tedious to enter those manually.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the community edition doesn't have this feature, which means you will have to buy the premium version to get the feature.

Comment: is there any free option like MySQL workbench which can generate reports?